# SQL Server Variable Truncate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know you could Truncate a Table or Table variable but is there a way to also truncate a variable ?

```
DECLARE @HiddenMe NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET  @HiddenMe = (select XYZ.abc)

If LEN(@HiddenME) >= 1800000  Then would like to truncate @HiddenMe .
```

Please let me know . FYI, am using sql 2008

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `TRUNCATE` in this context? (BTW you **can't** truncate a table variable.

Answer (score 2):

By truncate, I assume you mean truncating all data past a certain point, not dropping all data (like a table truncate). This should work.

```
SET  @HiddenMe=SUBSTRING(@HiddenMe,1,1800000)
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I want . Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`LEFT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx):

```
set @HiddenME = left(@HiddenME, 1800000)
```

So your script will be like this:

```
DECLARE @HiddenMe NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET  @HiddenMe = 'lets test a longish string to trim after a certain number of characters'

if LEN(@HiddenME) >= 1800000
  set @HiddenME = left(@HiddenME, 1800000)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7525)